# Cant find what is causing Segmentation fault (core dumped) in C

Tags: c

I am trying to get user input, write input to file, then use data for a structure. File compiles fine but after first input I get this error message:

```
$ gcc student.c -o student  
$ ./student  
Student First Name:  
alex  
Student Last Name:  
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Code:

```
/* student.h is to include the structure for stundent info */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {  
    char sID[9];
    char firstN[30];
    char lastN[30];
    }student[100];

#include "student.h"    
int main()
{
    FILE *sIf;
    int i;
    int num;
    student *sI;
    char *c;
    char *b;
    char *a;

    sIf = fopen("student.txt", "a+");
    if(!sIf)
    {
        printf("File could not be opened\n\a\a");
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }
    {
        printf("Student First Name: \n");
        scanf("%s", b);
        printf("Student Last Name: \n");
        scanf("%s", a);

        printf("Student ID Number: \n");
        scanf("%s", c);

        fprintf(sIf, "%s, %s\t%s\n", a, b, c);
    }

    fclose(sIf);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Allocate space for `a, b, c` or declare them as an array.

Comment: You should compile with `gcc -Wall -g student.c -o student` and you should debug using `gdb student`

Comment: It is odd that you have the `student` type defined outside the `"student.h"` header. It is also odd that you defined it as an array type. That will greatly complicate the use of it; the type of `sI` is a pointer to an array, and while that is OK sometimes, it is more likely to lead to confusion here. (It is also unused code in the progam shown — please review how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names and links for one idea.)

Answer (score 2):

1. Always use proper indentation while coding, this makes the code easy to read.
2. You are not allocating memory for your `char` pointers `a, b, c`.
3. Instead of `scanf()` use `fgets()` to accept the input strings.

Try this fixed code( I have included comments where necessary ).

```
/* student.h is to include the structure for stundent info */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
//#include "student.h"
typedef struct {
    char sID[9];
    char firstN[30];
    char lastN[30];
    }student[100];
int main()
{
    FILE *sIf;
    student *sI;//Why are you using it?
    char *ptr_pos;
    //Fix 1 Allocate space for a, b and c
    char *c=malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
    if(c==NULL)
    {
        puts("Failed to allocate memory for variable c");
        exit(1);
    }
    char *b=malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
    if(b==NULL)
    {
        puts("Failed to allocate memory for variable b");
        exit(1);
    }
    char *a=malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
    if(a==NULL)
    {
        puts("Failed to allocate memory for variable a");
        exit(1);
    }

    sIf = fopen("student.txt", "a+");
    if(!sIf)
    {
        printf("File could not be opened\n\a\a");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("Student First Name: \n");
    //Accept string using fgets, it prevents from overflow
    fgets(b,256,stdin);
    b[strlen(b)-1]='\0'; //Remove \n from the input string
    // Or you can use the following to remove `\n` from input string
    //if((ptr_pos=strchr(b, '\n')) != NULL)
    //  *ptr_pos = `\0`;


    printf("Student Last Name: \n");
    fgets(a,256,stdin);
    a[strlen(a)-1]='\0';

    printf("Student ID Number: \n");
    fgets(c,256,stdin);
    c[strlen(c)-1]='\0';

    fprintf(sIf, "%s, %s\t%s\n", a, b, c);       

    fclose(sIf);
    //Free allocated memory
    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(c);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Better to use buffer on stack (avoid memory leaks), and when strlen is 0 (empty input) it will corrupt the stack.

Comment: Where do you free thge allocated memory?

Comment: Check the memory allocations; check the return from `fgets()`; free the memory allocated.  And the code does not yet use the `student` type which is probably as well since `student *sI` is a pointer to an array which will cause confusion.